# How to put text at the top of subplots in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

If you don't know how to put text (using the text function so it can be more freely edited, not the legend function) at the top of each subplot in R when the coordinates vary and you don't know the y max or x max (e.g. for a histogram where you don't know the frequency in advance) how do you do it?

Addendum: Also, mtext uses margins, I am speaking of coordinate space here, not margin space.

Comment: Re: your addendum: But if you give pass `mtext` a negative value in the `line` argument, it goes inside the coordinate space. Is this a problem? If so, why?

Comment: Because you need to know in advance where the subplots will lie in regards to the margins.  I want this process to be automated, not something I have to play around with.  Mtext refers to the device margins not the plot coordinate space.

Comment: [possible dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322301/get-plot-bounding-box-values)

Comment: @rawr didn't notice that.  didn't turn up in my searches of the site.  I found it searching the R manual instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use par ('usr').  It gives you the current coordinates of the plot.  Really useful if you want text in a certain area of each subplot and you don't know the coordinates in advance (e.g. a histogram).  The output looks like:

```
par('usr')
[1] -0.28  7.28 -3.00 78.00
```

wherein the x min is the first member of the list, the x max is the second, the y min is the third, and the y max is the fourth.  You can treat par('usr') like a vector in R and if you want it to be in the top left you can do, say:

```
text(par('usr')[1]+2,.9*par('usr')[4],labels="blahblah")
```

From this it will be plotted in the upper 10% of the plot and +2 from the leftmost coordinate of the plot space.  Of course you can adjust this, but that would be top left more or less.

Using this code for my data:

```
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hist(y, breaks = 30)
text(.8 * par('usr')[2], .9 * par('usr')[4], labels = paste("mean:", round(mean(y), 2)))
text(.8 * par('usr')[2], .86 * par('usr')[4], labels = paste("median:", round(median(y), 2)))
hist(z, breaks = 30)
text(.8 * par('usr')[2], .9 * par('usr')[4], labels = paste("mean:", round(mean(z), 2)))
text(.8 * par('usr')[2], .86 * par('usr')[4], labels = paste("median:", round(median(z), 2)))
mtext("distributions", side = 3, line = -2, outer = TRUE, col = 2) # added mtext to show how I would use it to create a title
```

I got this image:

[image: myplot]

Comment: @rawr can you be a little more specific?

Comment: It's a much better answer! But reproducible would be nice. It's not reproducible because no one else has your data file. It would be a friendlier answer if you used a built-in data set or some simulated data. For whitespace, it'seasiertoreadcodeifyouuseyourspacebar ;)

Comment: For more reproducibility tips, you can [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). The ideal way to ask a question is to put data *in the question*, that way anyone who tries to answer has something to test on.

Comment: @Gregor ah, fair enough, I will use like rnorm(100) or something.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the text *inside* the plot region, you can use `legend`, and specify the position by keyword (see details in `?legend`):

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
sapply(1:4, function(i) {
  plot(runif(10))
  legend('top', paste('Plot', i), bty='n', text.font=2)
})
```

[image]

You could also use `mtext`:

```
mtext(paste('Plot', i), 3, line = -1.5)
```

Comment: Yes the way to paste text was not the problem as much as posting it in coordinate space while being able to freely edit it - and mtext and legend have some limitations in that regard.  But thanks.  That is still another way to do that.

Comment: @Gregor sure thing I will try to make it more specific...maybe specifying that i want to do it with text not legend.

Comment: @Gregor in the past there were certain pch characters I found I could add to a text box in R that could not be easily added to a legend the same way and so I prefer using the baser functions that can be more freely edited in my case just in case I want to add more things later.  There are limitations - though not many to what can be placed in a legend versus a text box.  Also, is that edit to the answer better?

Comment: @semjaavria No problem - I agree that using `text` with `par('usr')` is generally a more flexible approach. I just posted this to provide alternatives. :)

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer, it is a different way to look at it that is useful with the legend.  just not what I specifically was looking for.  however, I bet most people who come to this question will prefer your answer.